# How to get value from Pandas efficiently by specific row index and column name(index)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## How to get value from Pandas.DataFrame efficiently  by specific row index and column name(index)?

#### About the data

A Pandas DataFrame object, the DataFrame is about 1300 more line, 12 columns(eg: A, B, C, D ...),

#### Project Description

```
#### df stands for above data object(Pandas.DataFrame)
def task(df):
    t1 = time.time()
    # param contains values use to compare with df value.
    param = init_param()     
    #iter all rows 
    for x in range(len(df["A"])):
        # statistical(df, param) get df value and do some statistical work
        # eg:
        # df["A"][x] > df["A"][x-1]
        # df["B"][x] > param["f3"][x]
        # df['A'][x] > param["f1"][x] and df['B'][x- 1] < param['f2'][
        #  index - 1]
        # ...

        flag = statistical(x, df, param) 
        print(flag)

    print(time.time() - t1)
```

And the above task() function will execute under a large loop function.
EG:

```
 for x in range(10000):
     task()
```

#### My Question?

I want the task run more efficiently, I have done some test cases, the final result list below.

1. df["A"][x] seems not that efficient.
2. I try to convert df to dict(df.to_dict()) and do the same task, it seems much better, why?
3. Any other ideas? solution?

Comment: You could use `df.iat[x, df.columns.get_loc('A')]`, although I'd like to know what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thks, a parameter optimization engine.

Comment: The main issue is you aren't vectorising calculations. It would be helpful to know what kind of things you do in `doSth()`

Comment: @jpp all task job is get one df value and do some statistical calculations, no more other work. The main point here is How to make Like  df["A"][x] > df["A"][x-1] more efficient.

Comment: `df_dict = df.to_dict() `  df["A"][1] and df.iat[1, df.columns.get_loc('A')] and    df_dict["A"][1],  which operation is more efficent ?

Comment: First thing I'd say is you *never* need to do `for x in range(len(df['A'])): if df['A'][x] > 1000`, instead calculate your Boolean array beforehand in a *vectorised* fashion, i.e. *outside* the loop say `df['A'] > 1000` to get a Boolean `pd.Series`. Store the Boolean series in a variable and use it later.

Comment: @jpp thank a lot. Question updated, your are right,  the code mentioned in the question is sample code , not actual use case.